# BOM Preamble in .NET Rest API causing Twilio Parse Error 12100

Tags: c#, .net, rest, twilio, twilio-api

We have a .NET Rest API that is a web-hook for Twilio. It returns a TwilioResponse object.  Suddenly, Twilio is reporting a Parse Error 12100 on the hook. We looked closer and it seems to be due to a BOM preamble that is getting added to our response now (for some reason; this code hasn't changed in years).

Does anyone know what might cause this problem to suddenly crop up. And, more importantly, how can I fix it?

Here is the HttpGet method that Twilio is calling (and choking on)...

```
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("TransferMessage", Name = "GetTransferMessage")]
        public TwilioResponse GetTransferMessage()
        {
            var response = new TwilioResponse();
            response.Pause(2);
            response.Say("Hello. This call is being transferred by Acme Products and may be recorded " +
                "for quality assurance.");

            return response;
        }
```

Thanks in advance...!

Here is the xml returned by our endpoint. If you look at the raw data in a hex editor, it's clearly encoded with UTF-8-BOM.

[image]

Comment: Is this using ASP.NET on .NET Framework or ASP.NET Core? Also, could you share the resulting TwiML?

Comment: A couple of notes: `TwilioResponse` does not exist as far as I know, so is this a custom type in your project? Could you share the code of this `TwilioResponse`?
When I replace `TwilioResponse` with `VoiceResponse`, an empty JSON object is returned, when forcing XML, an empty XML response is returned: `<VoiceResponse xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />`.
We'll need some more information from you before we can help.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've attached a picture of the xml. It's the same xml we've been returning for years, except that now it's got the BOM preamble.

Comment: P.S. The TwilioResponse class is in the Twilio.TwiML helper library, I believe.

Comment: P.P.S The project is in .NET Framework 4.7.2.

Comment: I see, I do find traces of `TwilioResponse` on the C# SDK GitHub repo, although the latest mention of it was in 2015. So, it probably existed a long time ago.
Could you try to update to a more recent version of the Twilio C# SDK, and use `VoiceResponse` instead? You never know, maybe your issue was already fixed in a recent update.
(There's also a Twilio.AspNet.Mvc library that can make integrating TwiML with MVC easier.)

Comment: Did you find out what the issue was?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. We did not. We assume it's something environmental to our server, but we're still not sure. We'll probably end up refactoring to use a different method than TwilioResponse.

Comment: Let us know when you find out! Wish I could do more to help.